# How to filter using conditions in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset with over 600k obs in R. It looks something like this:

```
id <- c("58497484", "58544005", "74766653", "74764718", "62824455", "58497484", "58497484", "74766653")
key <- c("5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014", "2077485_02/06/1977_8_2014", "2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014", "2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017", "2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017", "2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016", "2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017", "2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019")
out <- c("2.1 - Reason 1", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.3 - Reason 3" , "1.2 - Reason 2", "3.6 - Reason 8")

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, key, out))
```

As you can notice, some of my ID numbers repeat themselves. What I need to do is group those IDs so I can see all obs that are grouped. I use this code to do so:

```
data <- data %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(duplicated(id), "", id))
```

When I do that, my df looks like this:

```
     id                  key                         out
    58497484     5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014      2.1 - Reason 1
                 2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016      1.3 - Reason 3
                 2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017      1.2 - Reason 2
    
    58544005     2077485_02/06/1977_8_2014      1.2 - Reason 2
    62824455     2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017     1.2 - Reason 2
    74764718     2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017     1.2 - Reason 2

    74766653     2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014      1.2 - Reason 2
                 2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019     3.6 - Reason 8
```

What I need to do now is filter my df using the variable "out", but I wanna keep all the registers  grouped if "out" starts with 2 or 3, so my df would look like this:

```
  id                  key                         out
58497484     5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014      2.1 - Reason 1
             2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016      1.3 - Reason 3
             2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017      1.2 - Reason 2       
74766653     2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014      1.2 - Reason 2
             2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019     3.6 - Reason 8
```

Is there any way I can do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you want to keep an `id` if _any_ of the `out` values start with a 2 or 3, not all of them.  Is that right?

Comment: @andrew_reece exactly!

Comment: Do you really need the `id` deleted if there is a duplicate?  Or do you just need the common `id` values to be grouped logically by R?  It seems like actually changing the duplicated `id` values to empty strings is more cosmetic than practical.

Comment: What do you mean by start with 2 or 3,  which one in `out` is the value ... ?

Comment: @andrew_reece I need to change it to empty strings because it gets easier to identify which obs belongs to that id, since I'm gonna present this df to my boss, it gets easier to understand. But you're right, it's totally cosmetic! :)

Comment: @TarJae What I mean is if any of the "out" variable rows string starts with either 2 or 3, I want to keep all the rows from the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the `duplicated` 'id' to blank (`''`), initially, do a group by `filter` first and then do the change on the 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   dplyr::filter(any(str_detect(out, "^(2|3)"))) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   arrange(id) %>%
   mutate(id = replace(id, duplicated(id), ""))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  id         key                        out           
  <chr>      <chr>                      <chr>         
1 "58497484" 5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014  2.1 - Reason 1
2 ""         2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016  1.3 - Reason 3
3 ""         2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017  1.2 - Reason 2
4 "74766653" 2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014  1.2 - Reason 2
5 ""         2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019 3.6 - Reason 8
```

Comment: i see my answer is basically the same as yours - i am happy to remove but am also curious whether OP really needs `id` turned to empty strings, if so then consider just dropping the `replace` line...

Comment: @andrew_reece sorry, I didn't see your answer.  was away.

Comment: @LanaMeijinhos As andrew_reece mentioned , replacing the duplicated elements to blank may not be  needed

Answer (score 1):

While akrun's is best approach I want to provide an alternative creating a helper column:

```
  data %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(key, out) %>% 
    mutate(x = as.integer(substr(out, 1,1))) %>% 
    filter(any(x %in% 2 | x %in% 3)) %>%     
    mutate(id = ifelse(duplicated(id), "", id)) %>% 
    select(-x)
```

```
  id         key                        out           
  <chr>      <chr>                      <chr>         
1 "58497484" 5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014  2.1 - Reason 1
2 ""         2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016  1.3 - Reason 3
3 ""         2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017  1.2 - Reason 2
4 "74766653" 2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014  1.2 - Reason 2
5 ""         2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019 3.6 - Reason 8
```