# How to delete rows using conditions in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a dataset with over 800k obs in R. It looks something like this:

```
id <- c("58497484", "58544005", "74766653", "74764718", "62824455", "58497484", "58497484", "74766653", "58544005")
key <- c("5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014", "2077485_02/06/1977_8_2014", "2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014", "2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017", "2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017", 
         "2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016", "2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017", 
         "2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019", "5718368_08/06/1982_3_2012")
out <- c("2.1 - Reason 1", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.2 - Reason 2", "1.3 - Reason 3" , 
         "1.2 - Reason 2", "3.6 - Reason 8", "3.2 - Reason 10")
flag1 <- c("1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0")
flag2 <- c("0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0")

data <- as.data.frame(cbind(id, key, out, flag1, flag2))
```

Some of my ID numbers repeat themselves. What I need to do is group those IDs so I can see all obs that are grouped. I use this code to do so:

```
data <- data %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% 
  mutate(id = ifelse(duplicated(id), "", id))
```

When I do that, my df looks like this:

```
   id                 key                        out         flag1   flag2
58497484     5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014      2.1 - Reason 1    1        0
             2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016      1.3 - Reason 3    1        1
             2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017      1.2 - Reason 2    0        0

58544005     2077485_02/06/1977_8_2014      1.2 - Reason 2    0        0
             5718368_08/06/1982_3_2012      3.2 - Reason 10   0        0

62824455     2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017     1.2 - Reason 2    1        0
74764718     2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017     1.2 - Reason 2    1        1

74766653     2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014      1.2 - Reason 2    1        0
             2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019     3.6 - Reason 8    1        1
```

What I need to do is DELETE clusters using "out", "flag1" and "flag2" variables as conditions. It goes like this: if any rows from my grouped id begin with "out" 2 or 3 AND if both "flag1" and "flag2" are equal to zero (0). My desired output is the following:

```
id                 key                        out         flag1   flag2
58497484     5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014      2.1 - Reason 1    1        0
             2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016      1.3 - Reason 3    1        1
             2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017      1.2 - Reason 2    0        0

62824455     2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017     1.2 - Reason 2    1        0
74764718     2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017     1.2 - Reason 2    1        1

74766653     2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014      1.2 - Reason 2    1        0
             2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019     3.6 - Reason 8    1        1
```

Notice that the "58544005" id number is not present in the output because it shows both flags equal to zero and "out" reason 3.2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like someone else is working on this data: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/70325584/2799941](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70325584/2799941)

Comment: @andrew_reece yeah, we both work at the same place! :)

Comment: The condition for deletion seems to have nothing to do with whether there are multiple rows per id. Can you clarify - are you simply looking to delete any rows where the three conditions you mentioned are true, or is there some consideration for id that should be included?

Comment: @kybazzi If the grouped id presents the 3 conditions, I want to delete it. ID "58544005" has "out" reason that starts with 3 and both flags equal to zero. ID "58497484" on the other hand has "out" reason that begins with 2, but it's row flags aren't equal to zero, just it's third row  that both flags equal to zero, so I want to keep this cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  arrange(id)%>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)%>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!(if_all(flag1:flag2, ~sum(.x)==0)& 
         any(substr(out, 1, 1) %in% 2:3))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(id = replace(id, duplicated(id), ''))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
  id         key                        out            flag1 flag2
  <chr>      <chr>                      <chr>          <int> <int>
1 "58497484" 5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014  2.1 - Reason 1     1     0
2 ""         2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016  1.3 - Reason 3     1     1
3 ""         2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017  1.2 - Reason 2     0     0
4 "62824455" 2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017 1.2 - Reason 2     1     0
5 "74764718" 2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017 1.2 - Reason 2     1     1
6 "74766653" 2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014  1.2 - Reason 2     1     0
7 ""         2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019 3.6 - Reason 8     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in the comments, it looks like you want to delete all records for id's where *any* record for that id satisfies the three conditions. Here's the strategy I will use:

1. For each individual row, check if the condition for deletion is satisfied.
2. For each id, check if any of its records were set to be deleted. If so, remove the id.

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  # Step 1: Create an indicator for deletion for each record
  mutate(
    delete_ind = 
      str_sub(out, 1, 1) %in% c("2", "3") & 
      flag1 == 0 &
      flag2 == 0
  ) %>% 
  # Step 2: Filter out all id's that satisfied the condition at least once
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(sum(delete_ind) == 0) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 7 x 6
  id       key                        out            flag1 flag2 delete_ind
  <chr>    <chr>                      <chr>          <chr> <chr> <lgl>     
1 58497484 5718368_09/06/1981_3_2014  2.1 - Reason 1 1     0     FALSE     
2 74766653 2091585_23/10/1982_1_2014  1.2 - Reason 2 1     0     FALSE     
3 74764718 2077388_30/01/2000_11_2017 1.2 - Reason 2 1     1     FALSE     
4 62824455 2082225_02/07/1998_10_2017 1.2 - Reason 2 1     0     FALSE     
5 58497484 2077450_04/05/2001_1_2016  1.3 - Reason 3 1     1     FALSE     
6 58497484 2077477_03/03/1978_8_2017  1.2 - Reason 2 0     0     FALSE     
7 74766653 2077388_30/01/2020_11_2019 3.6 - Reason 8 1     1     FALSE
```

Comment: I missed the part of your question regarding arranging by id and setting the id as `""` for duplicated cases - but it seems like you already have a solution to that part.